# Sort excel list by value

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a file that has 10 columns with varied data in each one. There is only one column that has (fairly) consistent data. I will attach the file so that hopefully it will help with what I am trying to do.

I want to have the unique values copy over to another worksheet. There are multiple ACD options, but I only want ACD to be copied IF the cell above it contains the value RING. Additionally, I would like to copy over the first TIME column, if possible the second. If necessary I will have a macro change the names to the second column to length.

[Data File](http://1drv.ms/1Aof5R6)

I know that advanced filters can be utilized but I have not yet been able to figure out how to properly set it up.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you needed? I'm pretty new to VBA though but it works.

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim lastrow As Long, LocY As Long, lastcopy As Long
Dim source As Worksheet, dest As Worksheet

Set source = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set dest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

lastrow = source.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Checks for the last row that contains data in the source
lastcopy = dest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Checks for the last row with data in the destination and move down by one to prime for data entry

For LocY = 2 To lastrow 'LocY referring to current location
    If source.Cells(LocY, 7).Value = "RING" Then 'Check if current locations at column 7 in source sheet contains the value RING
        source.Cells(LocY, 2).Copy 
        dest.Cells(lastcopy, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'pastes the value into the last row of destination sheet. 
        source.Cells(LocY, 7).Copy
        dest.Cells(lastcopy, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        source.Cells(LocY, 10).Copy
        dest.Cells(lastcopy, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        lastcopy = lastcopy + 1 'moves the target row in the destination down by one to prime for data entry.
    End If
Next
End Sub
```